# How can I split the JS and CSS into separate HTML files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I have a very specific requirement where I need to split the JS script tag into one file and the CSS link tag into another file using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

At the moment, *both* script and link tags are going into *both* files. Is there a way to do them separately?

Here is my current Webpack file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/app.bundle.css',
  allChunks: true
})

const createCSSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  chunks: ['app'],
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true
  },
  hash: true,
  template: 'src/ejs/css.ejs',
  filename: 'templates/css.php'
})

const createJSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  chunks: ['app'],
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true
  },
  hash: true,
  template: 'src/ejs/js.ejs',
  filename: 'templates/js.php'
})

const config = {
  entry: {
    'app': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist',
    filename: 'js/app.bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'js/app.bundle.map'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins () {
                return [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                      'last 2 versions',
                      'Safari >= 8',
                      'Explorer >= 9',
                      'Android >= 4'
                    ]
                  })
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'js/app.common',
      filename: 'js/app.common.js',
      minChunks: 2
    }),
    createCSSfile,
    createJSfile,
    extractCSS
  ]
}

export default config
```

Each `.ejs` file is empty and generates the following inside the `.php` files:

```
<head><link href="/dist/css/app.bundle.css?bdba9ec6846a7d92d61f" rel="stylesheet"></head><script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/app.bundle.js?bdba9ec6846a7d92d61f"></script>
```

Is there a way to separate them?

Also, I noticed it is inserting a `head` tag for the CSS link; is there a way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With help from @mootrichard I was able to get the answer I needed.

Steps to take:

1. Separate JS and CSS into their own entry points.
2. Set `inject: false` in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` configs to stop Webpack doing this.
3. Reference 'common' in the chunks to make the common JS file available for the templates.
4. Configure the `.ejs` templates to loop the files array.

**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/app.bundle.css',
  allChunks: true
})

const createCSSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  chunks: ['css'],
  excludeChunks: ['js', 'common'],
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    preserveLineBreaks: true,
    removeComments: true
  },
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  template: 'src/ejs/css.ejs',
  filename: 'templates/css.php'
})

const createJSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  chunks: ['js', 'common'],
  excludeChunks: ['css'],
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    preserveLineBreaks: true,
    removeComments: true
  },
  inject: false,
  hash: true,
  template: 'src/ejs/js.ejs',
  filename: 'templates/js.php'
})

const config = {
  entry: {
    'css': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
    ],
    'js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: 'js/app.bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'js/app.bundle.map'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins () {
                return [
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                      'last 2 versions',
                      'Safari >= 8',
                      'Explorer >= 9',
                      'Android >= 4'
                    ]
                  })
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      filename: 'js/app.common.js',
      minChunks: 2
    }),
    createCSSfile,
    createJSfile,
    extractCSS
  ]
}

export default config
```

**js.ejs**

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js.length; i++) { %>
  <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[i] %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

**css.ejs**

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css.length; i++) { %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[i] %>">
<% } %>
```

Hope this comes to help someone else in future.

**Benefit of this approach**

The reason I needed to separate out JS and CSS into actual separate files was for use in WordPress, where the templates do not have a concept of a 'master' template you inherit from, but instead has basic *footer* and *header* includes.

So if you're using WordPress then this is a pretty good approach to take.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're wanting to have separate files with different contents, you probably want to split up your entry points and the filter your chunks.

In both of your instances of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, you're setting `chunks: ['app']` which includes both your CSS and your JS.

You could have something like:

```
entry: {
  'js': [
     path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js')
  ],
  'css': [
     path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/app.scss')
  ]
},
```

Then you could have:

```
const createCSSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['css'],
    minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
    },
    hash: true,
    inject: false,
    template: 'src/ejs/css.ejs',
    filename: 'templates/css.php'
})

const createJSfile = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['js'],
    minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
    },
    hash: true,
    inject: false,
    template: 'src/ejs/js.ejs',
    filename: 'templates/js.php'
})
```

As for the CSS being included in the `<head>`, you'll want to set `inject: false` because you're utilizing your own custom templates for creating your HTML files. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration

Comment: I did actually try this prior to posting, but what happens is that the JS file gets the script tag, but the CSS file gets BOTH link AND script tag. Because of this, I also get an error (though it doesn't stop the build). "ERROR in chunk css [initial] js/app.bundle.js Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename js/app.bundle.js". Any further ideas?

Comment: Did you set `inject: false` when you did that?

Comment: No but if I do that then nothing is injected of course. Is there some level or combination to achieve this?

Comment: It seems that you don't want to use the standard `inject` features, and you're already using your own templates. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates  So you just want to set you template to manually create your `<link>` tag and not have webpack automatically inject the CSS and JS into your template.

Comment: Your answer and comments have helped guide me to a solution. I'll post my answer, but if you want to elaborate from my answer into your own, I'll then accept it as the solution. As it stands right now I can't accept this as a whole answer but also want to give credit where it's due.

Comment: No worries, I think your answer is on target and succinct. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the information about disabling `inject`, but feel its not necessary to include the information about the `.ejs` templates since those weren't actually provided in the question.